# How do I pass model values as javascript function parameters from inside an asp.net mvc Html helper such a Html.Radio?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

Okay, pretty simple question. I think I need to drop in some escape characters, but I'm not quite sure where.

Here is the javascript function I'm attempting to call:

```
function setData(associateValue, reviewDateValue) {
    var associate = document.getElementById("Associate");
    var reviewDate = document.getElementById("ReviewDate");
    associate.value = associateValue;
    reviewDate.value = reviewDateValue;
}
```

Here is the asp .net mvc line where I'm attempting to create a Radio button with a click event that calls the above function and passes data from the model as javascript parameter values.

```
<%= Html.RadioButton("Selected", item.Selected, new { onClick="setData('<%=item.Associate%>','<%=item.ReviewDate%>' )"  } )%>
```

The above throws a bunch of compile issues and doesn't work. A call such as the following does call the javascript, but doesn't get the data from the model.

```
<%= Html.RadioButton("Selected", item.Selected, new { onClick="setData('item.Associate','item.ReviewDate' )"  } )%>

<%= Html.RadioButton("Selected", item.Selected, new { onClick="setData('item.Associate','item.ReviewDate' )"  } )%>
```

Thoughts?

**SOLUTION**

```
        <% String functionCall = String.Format("setData('{0}','{1}')", Html.Encode(item.Associate), Html.Encode(item.ReviewDate )) ;  %>
        <%= Html.RadioButton("Selected", item.Selected, new { onClick=functionCall  } )%>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to properly build the string that represents the onclick evenet handler:

```
onClick = String.Format("setData('{0}', '{1}')", item.Association, item.ReviewData)
```

Comment: +1, simply add a HTML encode to ensure possible quotes in model data are properly escaped.

Comment: Love this answer marc. Very simple.

Answer (score 1):

It should be like this:

```
<%: Html.RadioButton("Selected", item.Selected, new { onClick="setData('" + Html.Encode(item.Associate) + "','" + Html.Encode(item.ReviewDate) + "' )"  } )%>
```

And if it's MVC2 you should prefer to use : instead of = to make sure it's HTML-encoded.

Comment: Note that `<%:` doesn't actually make any difference here, since Html.RadioButton returns an IHtmlString which won't be touched by `<%:`. However, it's good advice to get into the habit of using `<%:` by default, only using `<%=` when you know you need it.